# Hide grid fields based on value of dropdown selection

Tags: channel-entries, grid, editor

Is there a plugin around to hide grid fields based on value of dropdown selection?

So say the field is a dropdown and based on the selected option you then hide / show specific fields in the grid based on the selected option.

Kind of like this plugin but only for fields in a grid.

https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/entry-type

Answer (score 0):

Maybe missing your point, but not sure you need a plugin.

If you want to show / hide fields within a page without reloading it, you will need to use javascript to do this.  There are lots of answers within StackExchange in response to questions about this ([for example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30081134/show-and-hide-div-elements-based-on-dropdown-selection-in-html-using-javascript)), so easy to find a variety of solutions.

If this doesn't help, could you clarify what you are trying to do?

Comment: Guess I should have mentioned that I wanted this for the admin control panel when editing entries.